# Generations extension download for genealogy programs

Tags: gedcom

I restored my computer and lost my generation extension downloaded program.

Does anyone have this link?

It produced a small icon in the top left of my FTDNA program and other genealogy programs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link.  That is what I was looking for.  makes life a lot easier!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking about the Google Chrome extension that presents ancestors from FamilyTreeDNA in an Ahnentafel format, then the extension is called DNArboretum and is available here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dnarboretum/oekcehcnbnfmeimggmkfliochkojkaej